# Android : Error reporting using ACRA

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development. I've integrated ACRA library within my project for error reporting purpose. Crash report gets saved on ACRA storage if application crashes due to internal error. The application crashed when I hide the application and I reopened it after 1 hour. I guess it happened due to memory overuse issue. I checked ACRA storage but couldn't find error report there. Does ACRA report app crashes due to memory issues? Any ideas?

Comment: If you reopen app after 1 hour it's rather propably that it is null pointer exception because you didn't saved app state.

Comment: It's hard to help you when there's no codes to troubleshoot. Post your ACRA implementation.